# How to force a domain PC to use a specific DC?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, domain, domain-controller

How does a domain computer determine which DC to get GPO from?

How can I force a domain computer to use a specific DC?

I have some servers are getting GPO from a RODC on remote site. I need them to contact local DC instead.

Any hint?

Comment: You need to make sure that Active Directory Sites and Services is configured correctly with your Sites, Subnets and Domain Controllers.

Comment: If you're trying to "spoof" it you need to make all the _records in DNS resolve to the local DC only - you could hack the hosts file to do this but seems like a pain in the butt to me.

Answer (score 3):

Configure AD Sites as appropriate, and ensure that the correct DCs are assigned to each site.

Comment: Some links could make the answer more useful.

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/03/03/step-by-step-setting-up-active-directory-sites-subnets-site-links/